# Solving complex equation $ z+3\bar{z}=(2+i\sqrt{3})|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I struggle to solve this complex equation: $$ z+3\bar{z}=(2+i\sqrt{3})|z|$$
One way to resolve this is substitute |z| with $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ , $z=x+iy$, solve the cube etc,
but i did not reach the solution.

Any hint?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $4x-2iy=(2+i\sqrt{3})\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\iff 4x=2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\  \text{and}\ -2y=\sqrt{3}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$, then
$$4x-2iy=(2+i\sqrt{3})\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\iff 4x=2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\  \text{and}\ -2y=\sqrt{3}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$$
By the  equations, we know $x\geq 0,y\leq 0$, and both the two equations implies
$$y=-\sqrt{3}x.$$
So $$z=x-i\sqrt{3}x,x\geq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for appreciating my answer @ Amine

Answer (score 1):

First note that $z=0$ is (trivially) a solution.

Now, for other possible solution(s), divide thoroughout by $|z|$ ($z \ne 0$) to give:

$e^{i\theta} + 3e^{-i\theta} = 2+i\sqrt 3$ where $\theta$ is the argument of $z$.

You can let $e^{i\theta} = w \implies e^{-i\theta}= \frac 1w$ and you get a quadratic you can solve.

Comment: We can divide if $z\not=0$. Note  first that $z=0$ is a solution and THEN divide.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks, edited that in.

Comment: Yes i have tried this, we conclud that $\theta=\dfrac{-\pi}{3}$ is an argument of $z$ but what about the modulus of $z$? it still unkonow.

Comment: @Amine Any modulus works.

Comment: Thank you very much